# How to convert hexstring to ANSI (window 1252) and convert ANSI (window 1252) back to hex string in Java?

Tags: java, python

## How to convert hex string  to ansi (window 1252) and ansi (window 1252)to hex string in Java.

## python (Works perfectly)

```
q = "hex string value"

x = bytes.fromhex(q).decode('ANSI')

a = x.encode("ANSI")
a = a.hex()
if q==a:
    print("Correct")
```

## Java (This code has a problem)

```
String hexOri = "hex string value";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < hexOri.length(); i+=2) {
    String str = hexOri.substring(i, i+2);
    output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
}
System.out.println("ANSI = " + output);
char [] chars = output.toString().toCharArray();
StringBuffer hexOutput = new StringBuffer();

for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
  hexOutput.append(Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]));
}
System.out.println("HexOutput = " + hexOutput.toString());
System.out.println(hexOri.equals(hexOutput.toString()));
```

## Output from Python

Correct

## Expected Output from Python

Correct

## Output from Java

False

## Expected Output from Java

Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java the strings are encoded in UTF-16, so you can't read simply read/write the bytes of a string to get the encoding representation you desire.

You should use `String#getBytes(String str, String charset)` to get the string converted in the encoding you need and serialized to a byte array.

The same thing must be done to decode a byte array, using `new String(buffer,encoding)`.

In both cases if you use the method without the charset it will use the default encoding for the JVM instance (which *should* be the system charset).

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\tSome text [à]";

        try {
            System.out.println(str); //     Some text [à]

            String windowsLatin1 = "Cp1252";
            String hexString = toHex(windowsLatin1, str);

            System.out.println(hexString); // 09536f6d652074657874205be05d

            String winString = toString(windowsLatin1, hexString);

            System.out.println(winString); //   Some text [à]
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // Should not happen.
        }

    }

    public static String toString(String encoding, String hexString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        int length = hexString.length();
        byte [] buffer = new byte[length/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < length ; i+=2) {
            String hexVal = hexString.substring(i,i+2);
            byte code = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hexVal,16);
            buffer[i/2]=code;
        }
        String winString = new String(buffer,encoding);
        return winString;
    }

    public static String toHex(String encoding, String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(encoding);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            byte b = bytes[i];
            String hexChar = Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff);
            if(hexChar.length()<2) {
                builder.append('0');
            }
            builder.append(hexChar);
        }
        String hexString = builder.toString(); // 09536f6d652074657874205be05d
        return hexString;
    }
```

Comment: According to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc195054(v=msdn.10))  those are _unused_ character.
What char are they supposed to represent?

Comment: Based on my input value, I need to change cp1252 to cp1251. 

Is there any way to find the correct ANSI(1250, 1251, 1252, 1253, 1254, 1255, 1256, 1257, 1258, 1259, 1261, 1270) without doing IF ELSE in java? Like in python, they will select the correct ANSI.

Comment: I'm not sure a fully understand your problem. What you can do (no matter the language you use) is to convert from any _code page_ to unicode, but you can't fully convert from a _code page_ to another, without loosing something. You would not have different code pages in first place if they weren't distinct sets.
It is quite normal to have some character from the source set that cannot be mapped in the target set.

Comment: In python I just use ANSI, it will select the suitable one to encode or decode.
Is there anything similar in Java?